# Pass Java backreference to method parameter

Tags: java, regex, parsing, backreference

I need a Java port of this https://gist.github.com/jbroadway/2836900, which is basically a simple markdown regex parser in PHP.

I was hoping I could use the backreferences, but I can't make it work.
At the moment I'm not using a `HashMap`, I've got 2 JavaFX `TextArea`s where I'll get and set the text via a `ChangeListener`.

```
{ //...
htmlTextArea.setText(markdownTextArea.getText()
    .replaceAll("(#+)(.*)", header("$0", "$1", "$2"));
}

private String header(String text, String char, String content) {
    return String.format("<h%s>$2</h%s>", char.length(), char.length());
```

The backreference on $2 works, only if returned, but other backreferences don't. `char.length()` is always 2 since it's treated as `$2` and not as a backreference.

Id like to think of a solution where I can keep this style and don't need to handle this separately.

Comment: Your code has problems.  Can you show us a sample text which you are trying to match?  The `$1` capture group is the first matched group, not `$0` (which might be the entire input string).  Also, your pattern `(#+)(.*)` only has two capture groups, not three.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Isn't capture group 0 supposed to be the complete matched expression?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It's not clear to me that the OP intends to use the entire string, I would like to see some sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, since OP is trying to parse markdown headers, sample data is of the format `#Heading 1`, `##Heading 2` `###Heading 3`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the backreference values are only honored in the replacement string. As such, the values that are passed to your `header()` method are the `$0`, `$1` and `$2` literals and not the captured values.

Since there's no version of `replaceAll()` that accepts a lambda expression, I think your best bet would be to use a [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object:

```
String text = "###Heading 3";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(#+)(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();

while(m.find()) {
    int level = m.group(1).length();
    String title = m.group(2);

    m.appendReplacement(out, String.format("<h%s>%s</h%s>", level, title, level));
}

m.appendTail(out);

System.out.println(out.toString());
```

For the given input, this prints out:

```
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
```